# Strategies for copying data from a live MySQL database to a staging server

Tags: mysql

I have a live MySQL DB which is too large to regularly copy the live data to the staging server.

Is there a way of getting just the changes from the last week with the intention of running that script weekly? Would every table have to have an `updated` timestamp field added to it to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how large "too large to regularly copy" is, but I use [SQLyog](http://webyog.com/) to synchronize databases. It intelligently does insert/update/deletes for only the records that have changed. I recommend it highly.

Answer (score 4):

One way of going about this would be to make the staging server a replication slave of the production server.  However, if you don't want the staging machine to be constantly up to date with the production master, you can keep the slave mode turned off.

Then weekly, run a script that starts the slave for a few hours, allowing it to bring itself up to date with the master, and stop the slave again.

```
START SLAVE;
-- Wait a while
-- Trial and error to determine how long it takes to come into sync
STOP SLAVE;
```

This will save it in a state consistent with the master for the current week.  On the other hand, if you don't really need it as a weekly snapshot you can just leave the slave running all the time so it just stays in sync.